# Is there a way to access all the controllers from within an action method to review the ControllerDescriptor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection

In ASP.NET MVC I am looking to process, and display, all (or most) of the controller metadata when loading up a single page.

Say: `/home/index` would display all the controllers and their metadata.

Is there a good way to access the `ControllerDescriptor` for each controller? Maybe load them up calling into the controller factory? I really don't want to fall back to reflection for this type of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two extensions that do what you want (both on nuget)

There is phil haack's Controller Inspector :
http://www.codertakeout.com/v/4T4NO/Writing_an_ASPNET_MVC_Controller_Inspector.html
Nuget : https://preview.nuget.org/packages/MvcHaack.ControllerInspector
Github : https://github.com/Haacked/CodeHaacks

Then there is also Glimpse:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek5DebuggingASPNETMVCApplicationsWithGlimpse.aspx